# Deduplicating minidom xml output

Tags: xml, python-2.7, minidom

Is there any way of removing duplicates within an XML tree generated with minidom?
I've not attempted to do this yet, I'm just looking for something that already exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is because of this [Python bug 10131](http://bugs.python.org/issue10131). It is possible to work around it by using the 3rd party library [lxml](http://lxml.de). Using this library is recommended for other reasons too: easier syntax, speed, etc.

Comment: question raised from the dead